# Is there another method other than ctrl-p to get print dialog box in datatable print?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable, datatables

The user have to type Ctrl + P combination every time they want to print page after they get to print preview page clicking 'print' button.

Is there another way to do so? The button or something on print preview page so that I do not have to tell them every time I give support or due to their forgetfulness.

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right, you can do something like this (boostrap icon in this example):

```
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" onclick="javascript:window.print()"></span>
```